# Download an excel(.xlsx) file using blob in angular 2

Tags: angularjs, excel, download, blob, xlsx

How to download an .xlsx file saved in a angular 2 project folder from a browser using blob. I am able to download a csv by using the following code:

```
return this.http.get(fileUrl, {headers: headerInfo})
    .map((response: any) => {
        return new Blob([response._body], {type: 'text/csv'});
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably just use `fetch` and [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) to retrieve the Excel file:

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

// Client side.
// Note: it helps it server serves the appropriate response header, like e.g.
// 'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats'

return fetch(excelFileUrl, { headers: headerInfo })
  .then(res => res.blob()) // extract binary blob from response
  .then(blob => {
    // Download blob with file-saver
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "MyFile.xlsx");
  })
  .catch((err) => { console.error('Excel download failed', err); });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate!